# Colors in underbrace and overbrace - strange behaviour

Tags: color, amsmath, underbrace, overbrace

There is a strange inconsistency between `\overbrace` and `\underbrace` when one wishes to have the associated text (above or below) in a different color.

`\underbrace` behaves as expected and `\overbrace` does not -- both the text below the brace and above are changed by the color command, not just the raised text. To try to fix a `\color{black}` is required inside the `{}` for the lower text. However, the brace remains red. Is this an error in `xcolor`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,pdftex]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

$$\underbrace{x}_{\color{red} \sin t} \overbrace{x}^{\color{red} \sin t} \quad \overbrace{\color{black}x}^{\color{red} \sin t} $$

\end{document}
```

[image: Underbrace behaving, overbrace not, corrected (in part) by explicit \color{black} command]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't use `$$` in a LaTeX document to initiate and terminate display math mode; instead, use `\[` and `\]`. For more information on this issue, please see [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either use `\textcolor` instead of `\color` or enclose the whole superscript in an extra set of `{}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,pdftex]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\[\underbrace{x}_{\color{red} \sin t} \overbrace{x}^{\textcolor{red}{\sin t}} \quad \overbrace{x}^{{\color{red} \sin t}} \]

\end{document}
```