# Ungrouped \color breaks \limits

Tags: color, tex-core, math-operators, specials

Thinking about the issue posted in [Colors in underbrace and overbrace - strange behaviour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/575851/82917) I thought that the reboxing which TeX performs for a `\mathop` with `\limits` caused the color to leak outside of the current box. However, colour-leaking isn't the only problem, since also the behaviour of `\limits` is broken by a non-grouped `\color`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\hsize=5cm

Fine:
\[
\mathop{{\color{red} foo}}^{A}_{B}
\quad
\mathop{foo}^{{\color{red} A}}_{B}
\quad
\mathop{foo}^{A}_{{\color{red} B}}
\]

Not fine (well, the last \emph{is}):
\[
\mathop{\color{red} foo}^{A}_{B}
\quad
\mathop{foo}^{\color{red} A}_{B}
\quad
\mathop{foo}^{A}_{\color{red} B}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, grouping is the correct way to go; but I'm curious why the colour `\special` breaks the correct limit placement.

Comment: this is basically the whole "color safe" boxing introduced in latex2e, why `\sbox` adds an extra group `\color` inserts a color restore whatsit via `\aftergroup` and that whatsit comes where it comes... The extra group keeps it in the superscript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}\showoutput
\begin{document}
\hsize=5cm
\[
\max^{{\color{red} A}}
\]
\[
\max^{\color{red} A}
\]

\end{document}
```

This is the same issue as the "colour safe groups" introduced for `\sbox` etc.

`\color` introduces a color restore via `\aftergroup` and without the extra group this drops out of the superscript.

the log shows.

```
...\hbox(12.08887+0.0)x18.61118, shifted 61.82631, display
....\vbox(12.08887+0.0)x18.61118
.....\kern1.0
.....\hbox(4.78334+0.0)x18.61118, glue set 6.29863fil
......\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
......\hbox(4.78334+0.0)x6.01392
.......\pdfcolorstack 0 push {1 0 0 rg 1 0 0 RG}
.......\OML/cmm/m/it/7 A
......\pdfcolorstack 0 pop
```

with the grouped case the color pop comes after **A**

but with the ungrouped case

```
.....\hbox(4.78334+0.0)x18.61118, glue set 6.29863fil
......\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
......\pdfcolorstack 0 push {1 0 0 rg 1 0 0 RG}
......\OML/cmm/m/it/7 A
......\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.....\kern1.99998
.....\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x18.61118
......\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 m
......\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 a
......\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 x
....\pdfcolorstack 0 pop
```

the color pop comes after **max**

[image]

---

In the cases that you show with a B not under max the color restore whatsit has been placed before the `_B` so it is subscripting that node, not the mathop.